# How to get rid of unused suggested tags on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-tags

Suggested tags are useful most of the time, but if I make a typo and then reblog, then go back and fix it, Tumblr still saves that tag, which is very annoying. Even if I delete the tag from all posts with the typo, it still keeps it. Is there any way to get rid of these or some script I can download?

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, once a misspelled tag is removed from every post, it has not shown up in the tag suggestions, *except before the last removal has been saved*.

Make sure that you have, indeed, removed the typo from all of your posts. The search feature is a miracle tool for doing this; combine that with the Mass Post Editor (`https://www.tumblr.com/mega-editor/[your blog URL/username]`) for maximum efficiency if you have a misspelled tag in several posts.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, misspelled tags still show up on my reblogs. It is useful to help track them down though.